# MongoDB / C#: checking if documents from an array exist without returning them

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to find the fastest way to know if a number of documents exist in MongoDB. I don't need the documents themselves, just a confirmation of their existence.

Let's assume I have this list:

```
var L = new List<string> {"1", "3", "A"};
```

and I want to find if these documents exist.

One way to do is it like this (syntax may be a bit off since I'm trying this from memory, but the idea is there):

```
find(Query.In(_ => _._id, L));
```

and it works, but it returns all the documents as well, which is a waste of time

So, I get only the ids, through projection:

```
find(Query.In(_ => _._id, L)).Project(Projection.Expression(_ => _._id));
```

and this works very well and returns me a list of existing ids.

The question is: is it efficient to find/project? or is there a faster way to achieve the same?

(bonus question: how can I do query.in with the fluent syntax? :))

Comment: Not sure what version of the MongoDb Driver you are using, but the v2.4 has a Count() method that takes a FilterDefinition.  That should get you the count that you need,.

Comment: I have 3.4 ; count will not be able to tell me which of the documents exist though, just how many.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing it is, on my opiniion ok. I would do the same. `Project` step is executing on server, so you don't get the complete documents, just Ids, it's exact that you want.

You could do the same query with fluent syntax, it's just (i assume your collection in the `collection` variable):

```
collection.Find(_=>L.Contains(_._id)).Project(_=>_.Id).ToList();
```